# Delete the empty cells row wise ,to move the cell value in a group as i want

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove the empty elements in a cell, row wise to move the cell value from right to left in a group of column from A to E, example below

```
A   B   C   D   E            
                3
    3       2   
6       2   2   
    1   6       
2   3           
    6   6   6   
1       1
```

What i want is

```
A   B  C   D   E
3   3  2   6   2
2   1  6   2   3
6   6  6   1   1
```

resulting data (solution) should start from A1 as mentioned above,

Answer (score 1):

Select the area you wish to "compact" and run this:

```
Sub CompactData()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    r.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

So if we start with this:

[image]

we will result in this:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

From your comments you may need a **serpentine** compression.  If that is the case then:

```
Sub SerpentineMotion()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, c As Collection
    Dim K As Long
    Set c = New Collection
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("A:E"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            c.Add r.Value
        End If
    Next r

    rng.Clear
    K = 1

    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = c.Item(K)
        K = K + 1
        If K > c.Count Then Exit Sub
    Next r

End Sub
```

Which will convert:

[image]

Into:

[image]

Comment: Sir am not getting what i want, actually given data has to be arranged in A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 then B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 then c1......like this ,depending on number of available digit, and for your information there will be digits from 0-9,

Comment: sorry please remove my previous comment one correction it has to be arranged in A1 B1 C1 D1 E1  then A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 , then A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 like this